# glfwGetCursorPos makes the y Coordinate smaller by 172 every second frame

Tags: c++, glfw

I've been having the weirdest problem ever. I've made a piece of code that sets the cursor position to the centre of the screen and every frame calculates the movement of the cursor. Everything worked, until it didn't. Today I woke up and suddenly when I call `glfwGetCursorPos`, the y coordinate it gives me, keeps getting smaller by 172 every second frame.

Example Code:

```
double testX, testY;
glfwGetCursorPos(window, &testX, &testY);
std::cout << testY << std::endl;
```

this piece of code gets called every frame. I tried making the testX and testY variable global, setting them to zero before and after the `glfwGetCursorPos` function call, nothing works. This is the output I'm getting

[image]

The first one is correct, it's the cursor position before it gets set to the centre. The next Two are also correct as they are the centre Y coordinate that they are supposedto be. However after that, I don't move the cursor a single bit, no input at all, and every second frame, `testY` becomes smaller by exactly 172.

I figured out that this gets caused by Setting the Cursor Position (Which I do like this)

```
glfwSetCursorPos(window, centre.x, centre.y);
```

If I remove this line, `glfwGetCursorPos` gives me a normal value. However, I found out that this line of code only causes issue if I hide the cursor. If the cursor never gets hidden and I keep setting the cursor pos to the centre, everything works.
I hide the cursor like this:

```
glfwSetInputMode(window, GLFW_CURSOR, GLFW_CURSOR_DISABLED);
```

If I use GLFW_CURSOR_HIDDEN everything works, but the Cursor doesn't get hidden and is still visible. Does anyone know what's happening ?

EDIT: For some reason, when I disable the mouse cursor using `GLFW_CURSOR_HIDDEN`, it works in a different place in my code, but if I do it from somewhere else, it doesn't work for some reason

Comment: If the cursor is hidden there might not even be a cursor, depending on the platform

Comment: But it literally worked yesterday, I'm on the same computer, and it always worked, I have a similar piece of code, that does literally the same exact thing and it works without an issue and has worked for months

Comment: windows update? compiler update? if there is no cursor why do you need to know where it is? I'm reasonably sure that at least one platform actually stops tracking the cursor position when it's invisible, though I don't remember where I saw that - it stops tracking the cursor position and just tells you how much the mouse moved, instead.

Comment: I might have to check for updates because I can't find any reason why this might be happening. And also I need it for a Camera controller. I want to measure how much the mouse has moved in what direction to properly rotate the camera. And It could be windows, but as I said, the literal exact same piece of code works and has been working for months. But I'm going to check for any compiler or windows updates

Comment: Maybe you ran some old code yesterday which wasn't the code you thought that runs. I'd like to see a [mre]. Please create a copy of your code and remove everything which is not needed to see the problem in action.

Comment: That can't be possible, I literally revert my github repo to the last push I made which worked, It's literally the exact same code that worked yesterday. Although I found out that if I use GLFW_CURSOR_DISABLED this happens. but If I use GLFW_CURSOR_HIDDEN it doesn't hide the cursor, even though it hides the cursor when I call it in a different class.

Comment: And also, I don't think It might be possible for me to make a minimal reproducible example since it's from a Game Engine I've been working on, and the code relevant to this is spanned across multiple files, scopes and even projects and languages

Comment: then you have to delete all that other stuff to make a minimal reproducible example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it finally. The reason it was doing this is because I was hiding the cursor using GLFW_CURSOR_DISABLED which for some reason broke it. However, once I switched to GLFW_CURSOR_HIDDEN it worked, but it wouldn't hide the cursor. The reason why was that ImGui (UI Library im using) was showing the cursor every single frame. So if I did hide the cursor, ImGui will make it visible again. I just had the comment out the line in ImGui that did this. Not the best solution, but I couldn't find any other way to fix it.

Comment: GLFW_CURSOR_DISABLED makes it act like there is no cursor. There aren't valid cursor coordinates. Behind the scenes GLFW keeps teleporting the cursor to the middle of the window so it can't move outside and the player can keep moving it forever. GLFW_CURSOR_HIDDEN is just a normal cursor but invisible.

Comment: Yeah I figured it out finally. However I don't understand the fact that I did the exact same thing (with _DISABLED) somewhere else in my code, it worked, but if I did it in a different place it Didn't. But I finally fixed it